# How to use a scanf, printf and fgets together in sequence

Tags: c

So I'm stuck on this one. When I put an fgets after scanf, the fgets couldn't store space inputs. A quick googling taught me that `This happens because every scanf() leaves a newline character in a buffer that is read by the next scanf.` and putting a space or newline at the end of the control string fixes it... Yep it did but the problem I am facing is that if there's a printf between scanf and fgets, the fgets work before the printf.

So, I need an explanation for this behavior + any solutions/workarounds if any.

Compiler/Platform used: `gcc 11/Linux`

Here is the code  (LOOK AT LINE 24-27 for example)

```
/*Write a program to create a structure of employees containing the following data members: Employee ID, Name, Age, Address, Department and Salary.
 Input data for 10 employees and display the details of the employee from the employee ID given by the user.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int i=0;
   typedef struct employee
   {
      long int id;
      char name[30];
      int age;
      char address[100];
      char dept[30];
      long int salary;
   }emp;

   emp list[5];

   for (i = 0; i<10;i++)
   {
      printf("Enter id of employee %d : ", i+1);
      scanf("%ld ", &(list[i].id));
      printf("Enter name of employee %d : ", i+1);
      fgets(list[i].name, 30, stdin);
      printf("Enter age of employee %d : ", i+1);
      scanf("%d ", &(list[i].age));
      printf("Enter address of employee %d : ", i+1);
      fgets(list[i].address, 100, stdin);
      printf("Enter dept of employee %d : ", i+1);
      fgets(list[i].dept, 30, stdin);
      printf("Enter salary of employee %d : ", i+1);
      scanf("%ld ", &list[i].salary);
   }

   long int emp_id;
   int flag=0;
   printf("Enter employee id to be searched: ");
   scanf("%ld", &emp_id);

   // Linear search
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      if (list[i].id==emp_id)
      {
         printf("Employee found!!");
         flag=1;
         printf("Id : %ld \n", list[i].id);
         printf("Name : %s \n", list[i].name);
         printf("Age : %d\n", list[i].age);
         printf("Address : %s \n", list[i].address);
         printf("Dept : %s \n", list[i].dept);
         printf("Salary : %ld \n", list[i].salary);
      }
   }
   if (flag==0)
   {
      printf("Employee not found!!");
   }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Generally, questions are of higher quality if they provide a [mre] of the problem. I have the impression that it should be possible to demonstrate the problem with less code.

Comment: Please post the output of the program as text, not as an image. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: The answer to the title is, "just don't". `fgets` and `scanf` were not designed to work well together. If you're going to use `fgets`, then read every line of the input with `fgets`. For those lines that contain numbers, use `sscanf` or functions like `strtol` to convert the strings to numbers. For those lines that are just strings, remember to [remove the newline that `fgets` puts in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776).

Comment: Rather than magic numbers like 100, `fgets(list[i].address, sizeof list[i].address, stdin);` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yep it did but the problem I am facing is that if there's a printf between scanf and fgets, the fgets work before the printf.

That description is not accurate.

The problem is rather the following line:

```
scanf("%ld ", &(list[i].id));
```

As stated in the [documentation of the `scanf` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), the space character in the format string will not only match a single space character, but as many as possible. Therefore, this line of code will first read a number and then continue reading and discarding whitespace characters until a non-whitespace character is encountered.

Since you are probably using a terminal that is line-based, this means that it will have to enter at least a whole line of extra input, before the function `scanf` finds a non-whitespace character and returns.

Therefore, I recommend that you remove the space character from the format string, and that you use a different method of discarding the leftovers of the line after the `scanf` function call. You could simply call [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) to consume the newline character, and then discard it. However, this will only work if the next character actually is the newline character. A more robust method of discarding the leftovers of a `scanf` function call would be the following loop:

```
int c;

do
{
    c = getchar();

} while ( c != EOF && c != '\n' );
```

This loop will continue discarding characters until it encounters the newline character, or if end-of-file or an error occurs.

After fixing your program, it should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void discard_remainder_of_line( void )
{
    int c;
    
    do
    {
        c = getchar();

    } while ( c != EOF && c != '\n' );
}

int main()
{
   int i=0;
   typedef struct employee
   {
      long int id;
      char name[30];
      int age;
      char address[100];
      char dept[30];
      long int salary;
   }emp;

   emp list[5];

   for (i = 0; i<10;i++)
   {
      printf("Enter id of employee %d : ", i+1);
      scanf("%ld", &(list[i].id));
      discard_remainder_of_line();
      printf("Enter name of employee %d : ", i+1);
      fgets(list[i].name, 30, stdin);
      printf("Enter age of employee %d : ", i+1);
      scanf("%d", &(list[i].age));
      discard_remainder_of_line();
      printf("Enter address of employee %d : ", i+1);
      fgets(list[i].address, 100, stdin);
      printf("Enter dept of employee %d : ", i+1);
      fgets(list[i].dept, 30, stdin);
      printf("Enter salary of employee %d : ", i+1);
      scanf("%ld", &list[i].salary);
      discard_remainder_of_line();
   }

   long int emp_id;
   int flag=0;
   printf("Enter employee id to be searched: ");
   scanf("%ld", &emp_id);
   discard_remainder_of_line();

   // Linear search
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      if (list[i].id==emp_id)
      {
         printf("Employee found!!");
         flag=1;
         printf("Id : %ld \n", list[i].id);
         printf("Name : %s \n", list[i].name);
         printf("Age : %d\n", list[i].age);
         printf("Address : %s \n", list[i].address);
         printf("Dept : %s \n", list[i].dept);
         printf("Salary : %ld \n", list[i].salary);
      }
   }
   if (flag==0)
   {
      printf("Employee not found!!");
   }
}
```

As you can see, at least the first part of your program appears to work now:

```
Enter id of employee 1 : 264
Enter name of employee 1 : John Doe
Enter age of employee 1 : 22
Enter address of employee 1 : 43 Third Street
Enter dept of employee 1 : Computer Science
Enter salary of employee 1 : 5000
Enter id of employee 2 : Jane Doe
Enter name of employee 2 : 21
Enter age of employee 2 :
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the convention you use with the space at the end of the `scanf` format string does not really consume the `\n`. As a result `fgets` consumes it and skips the string input. It really has nothing to do with the `printf`.

The way to solve this is to explicitly consume the newline like so: `scanf("%ld%*c", &i)`. The `*` is a suppressing character which tells `scanf` to consume the input but not try to assign it to a variable and the `c` conversion specifier asks to read any character. So we ask `scanf` to read one `char` after the `long int` but not assign it to a variable. If this `char` happens to be a newline everything will be OK (But if not - trouble again). Please read the documentation at [scanf, fscanf, sscanf, scanf_s, fscanf_s, sscanf_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

I would also recommend you add a call to `fflush(stdout);` after every `printf` because your are not using a newline to terminate your prints.

As a final note. It is probably best that you read all your input using `fgets` which will properly handle any input terminated by a newline (also on systems where the newline is not just one character). Once you read the input as a string you can use sscanf or other functions to correctly parse it.

Comment: `scanf("%ld%*c", &i)` will only work if the next character is the new line character. Although your solution will probably work in most cases, a more robust solution would keep reading characters until it encounters a newline character. For example, your solution will fail if the user enters `32 ` as input (note the trailing space character).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You are correct and I mentioned this in the answer. That is also why I added the recommendation to read everything using fgets and parse it later