# Why does my program print invisible chars instead of string?

Tags: arrays, c, string, printf

I need to write a program in C that receives a number N and N×words(strings). Finds the word with the minimum number of characters, reduces every other word to the min character size and then prints them in reverse order in which they were given. But nothing appears after print. It's like it prints spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int N, min, i;
  char S[100][51], gra[51];

  scanf("%d", &N);

  if (N < 1 || N > 100) {
    printf("Wrong Input");

    return 1;
  }

  min = 52;

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    fgets(S[i], 51, stdin);

    S[i][strcspn(S[i], "\n")] = '\0';

    if (strlen(S[i]) < min) {
      min = strlen(S[i]);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    S[i][min + 1] = '\0';
  }

  i = N - 1;

  do {
    strncpy(gra, S[i], min + 1);

    printf("%s ", gra);

    i--;
  } while (i >= 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show a simple example of input and expected output

Comment: Not causing your current issue but you should get used to **always** check the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

The *main* issue with your code is that the `scanf("%d", &N);` leaves a newline in the input buffer after it has read the `N` value. Thus, the first run of the subsequent `for` loop reads an empty string, so the `min` value will be set to zero. This problem is discussed at length here: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/10871073) <sup>1</sup>. A simple way of clearing this is to add a `scanf("%*c");` line between reading the `N` and starting your loop, but there are other ways given in the answers to the linked questions.

With that fixed, you still have some issues: note that array indexes begin at **zero** in C; so, to truncate a string to only `min` characters, you need to add the `nul` terminator (`'\0'`) at `S[i][min]`, *not* at `S[i][min+1]`, as you are doing.

Further, with that terminator added, you don't need to use `strncpy` – a simple `strcpy` will suffice.

Here's a version of your code with the aforementioned fixes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int N, i;
    char S[100][51], gra[51];

    int valid = scanf("%d", &N);
    if (valid != 1 || N < 1 || N > 100) {
        printf("Wrong Input");
        return 1;
    }
    scanf("%*c"); // Clear leftover newline from input buffer

    size_t min = 52; // The "size_t" type is a better fit for `strlen`
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fgets(S[i], 51, stdin);
        S[i][strcspn(S[i], "\n")] = '\0';
        if (strlen(S[i]) < min) {
            min = strlen(S[i]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        S[i][min] = '\0'; // Array indexes start at zero, so add null at [min], not [min+1].
    }

    i = N - 1;
    do {
        strcpy(gra, S[i]); // Don't need strncpy: a nul terminator has been added to limit length
        printf("%s ", gra);
        i--;
    } while (i >= 0);

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See also: [How to use a scanf, printf and fgets together in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71366331/10871073)